# Ruby - Why unserialization from JSON is outputting Array instead of my class?

Tags: json, ruby, serialization

I'm doing a simple hangman game in Odin Project with an option to save and load game.

I have already serialized my class in JSON and save it to file which contents look like this:

```
{"@password":["p","r","o","f","u","s","e","l","y"],"@password_checked":["_","_","_","_","u","_","_","_","_"],"@chances":8,"@picked_letters":["u","a"]}
```

My methods to serialize and unserialize come from https://www.sitepoint.com/choosing-right-serialization-format/ and they look like this:

```
 require 'json'

module BasicSerializable

  @@serializer = JSON

  def serialize
    obj = {}
    instance_variables.map do |var|
      obj[var] = instance_variable_get(var)
    end

    @@serializer.dump obj
  end

  def unserialize(string)
    obj = @@serializer.parse(string)
    obj.keys.each do |key|
      instance_variable_set(key, obj[key])
    end
  end
end
```

My code to unserialize look like this

```
file = File.new(game_to_load, 'r')
serialized_object = file.gets     # serialized_object is the file from above
p @password.class                           #=> Password
@password = unserialize(serialized_object)
p @password.class                           #=> Array
p @password     #=> ["@password", "@password_checked", "@chances", "@picked_letters"]
```

The problem is that I can't figure out why unserialization of `serialized_object` is outputting me the Array. How to make it to output my class with the state of object saved in a file mentioned in the beginning?

Comment: Where is that unserializing code at the end? Is it in a class? Or is it sitting in the main code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call `unserialize` on the `@password` object, so it's going to be called on the current object. You didn't show what that is, but I guess it's an Array.

Instead you want `@password.unserialize`.

---

Some notes...

Since `unserialize` changes the object and blows away existing data, it should probably be `unserialize!`.

Note that Ruby already has a [Marshal class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Marshal.html) to do serialization and deserialization. It's in a binary format, not JSON.

Storing your passwords as clear text is a ***really*** bad idea. Passwords should never, ever, ***EVER*** be stored, only their hashes. Good hashing means if the password file is stolen, there's additional hurdles for the attacker to jump. If you do it right, they're nigh unbreakable.

See [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Comment: Yes. `@password.unserialize(serialized_object)` solved it. Thanks Schwern. I tried to debug this for three hours now.

Comment: Thanks for tips. In fact, this exercise is focused on saving and loading state of classes, which can be anything, instead of a password to the hangman. I don't want to go down the rabbit holes right now. Time will come for learning about security. I've skimmed your link to password hashing and save it in bookmarks. For now, I'm treating it only as a brief intro.

Comment: @ToTenMilan Oh, whew, it's not an actual password! I was wondering why its stored as a list of characters.